# HTML meta stop auto refresh after onclick button

Tags: html, meta

I am using a very simple html auto refresh as below to auto trigger refresh my webpage.
This function works perfectly until I onClick on any html button on the same page, the page will stop auto refresh.

```
<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='60'>
```

As a simple summary, the auto refresh function will stop working if there is any action triggered on the page alike clicked a button on the page. Any solution on this issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JS for that:

```
var timer = setTimeout(function () {
    window.location.reload()
}, 60000);
```

This code will reload your webpage after 60 milliseconds.

You can cancel reload using it's reference `timer`:

```
clearTimeout(timer);
```